# projectile suggests a file that does not exist

Tags: projectile

I am just starting to test projectile.

My understanding is that `projectile-find-file` looks into my whole repository for the file I'm looking for.

I am also currently working on the file structure of my project. When trying to open a file (one I have moved), both the new and the old location show up as suggestion. If I choose the old location, a new file is created.

My questions:

- is the file location information cached somewhere, in that case where? I installed projectile *after* moving the file. How can I clean the old info?
- is there a way to prevent projectile from creating files? I'm happy with returning to `ido-find-file` for file creation.

---

More details: I am upgrading an SDK that is a submodule of my repo, and the new version has another file structure.

```
# the old file (note the "old" in the path):
vendor/nrf5-sdk-old/components/drivers_nrf/spi_master/nrf_drv_spi.h
# the new file:
vendor/nrf5-sdk/integration/nrfx/legacy/nrf_drv_spi.h
```

When I run `projectile-find-file` in my project:

[image]

Note the second suggestion, which is a file that does not exist. What exists is this file, *but in nrf-sdk-old* instead of nrf-sdk as advertized.

I've tried moving away the `nrf-sdk-old` altogether, the suggestion keeps coming up.

EDIT: I've tried removing my TAGS file. The old path is still in my checked out commit, though (but not in working files). Could that be it?

Comment: if `C-c p f` is `projectile-find-file` type `C-u C-c p f` and it'll automatically delete the cache and repopulate the cache with the latest files

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan mmm, "Wrong type argument: hash-table-p, nil"

Comment: enable toggle-debug-on-error and run the command again. You shouldn't get that error. Try filing an issue in `projectile` or check your `init.el` configuration

Answer (score 1):

`C-c p i` -- invalidate cache, `projectile-invalidate-cache`.

For windows the next cache 'repopulation' might be quite slow. You can use `ripgrep` to greatly spead it up.

Comment: Good to know! Unfortunately I still get one more hit compared to `find -name`.

Comment: `C-u C-c p f` automatically invalidates the cache and repopulates it again. No need to manually invoke `projectile-invalidate-cache`

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan yes I know, thx. But for me personally it is easier to invalidate cache and then call find file again.